# How to make dhcpd recognize a new interface without restart

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, dhcp, daemon

I'm working on automatizated virtualization but currently i'm stuck with setting up the DHCP server. The problem is, every time i create a virtual machine, i have to restart the daemon to register the new interface (all machines have their own nif because of performance & security). Is there any way to make the DHCP daemon recognize the new interface and handle packets on it without restarting the daemon?

Comment: Are you creating a new NIC on the DHCP server for each new network? And that's what you need the DHCP daemon to start listening on?

Comment: Exactly, every new machine gets a new network interface.

Comment: But why does your DHCP server care?

Comment: Because i want it to assign an address to the newly created virtual machine.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro There you go.

Comment: Why aren't you using libvirt?

Comment: Libvirt uses dnsmasq (as far as i know). I didn't try that yet but if i can't solve this, i will definitely take a look at it, thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

In ISC DHCP, it is not a "bug", it is a feature. The configure file is only read when you restart the daemon.

As such, if dealing only with the text configuration file, you can only provision new IP addresses/MACs adding to the text configuration file *and* restarting the DHCP daemon.

A more clean and modern approach may be using instead of ISC-DHCP the [Kea](https://kea.isc.org/wiki) DHCP server, also from ISC. Kea also hasvan hook mechanism and plug-ins, that might fit (or not) your needs.

> Kea DHCP Server Kea is an open source DHCPv4/DHCPv6 server being
>   developed by ​Internet Systems Consortium. Kea is a high-performance,
>   extensible DHCP server engine that is designed to be easily modified
>   and extended with hooks libraries.
>
> Kea is free open source, and we welcome community engagement, via the
>   ​Kea-users mailing list, this wiki, and our ​Github repository. There
>   is a small core team of dedicated software engineers developing it and
>   we need your ​contributions and ​support contracts to support them.

The backend can be MySQL, and you may deal with it with SQL queries instead of having to deal with a text file and (re)starts of the DHCP daemon.

PS. To provision things in DHCP, in the past I used an ISP DHCP hacked version to sit on top of MySQL that was very specific of the cable ISP industry, but sadly the project was abandoned. Kea should somewhat offer similar functionalities nowadays.

Comment: I knew about OMAPI, but does it allow adding interfaces also? As far as i know it's only handling leases, static hosts and stuff like those.

Comment: Not sure, the documentation on some parts says it is possible, in others not. However nowadays, it makes much more sense using Kea on top of MySQL. I dealt in the past both with text and then with ISC DHCP on top of MySQL, and in the latter case the provisioning code and checking out for corner cases is so much more simpler.